# How to pass strings from multiple dart files and get it to one dart file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to send the data's of different dart files to one dart file in flutter? I need to get strings from different dart files in a dart file.

Comment: Can I see your file system and the place where you define Strings and where you want to use that Strings?

Comment: Wherever I can use the strings but I need to get those strings in my dart file.

Comment: You should edit your question for better understanding and add much more detail, So others can first know your problem better to answer it.

Comment: Bro I need to get strings from different dart files in one dart file. How to use constructor for that?

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose this is the file system of Your project.**

[image: Explorer]

- `CS.dart` and `CU.dart` are the files where Strings is defined.
- You want to use that Strings in the `CategoryScreen.dart` file.

**Then you have to write these lines of code in your `CategoryScreen.dart` at the top of any other code.**

```dart
import 'package:demo_app/utils/CS.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/utils/CU.dart';

...REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
```